# Where am i going wrong with my decryption

Tags: c++, visual-c++, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a .bin file that I don't know the key for to answer this question we were given in class:
 8) Suppose you didn't know the value of “key” you'd used in 6). Can you still decrypt an encrypted file? If so write a program that will do this.
**(No marks, this one's just for fun!)**
[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZKnx.png)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {                               
uint8_t c, key = 0, uintOutput = 0;
string Encrypted, everything[255];
char b, charOutput;
int x = 0;
while ((b = getchar()) != EOF) {
    Encrypted = Encrypted + b;                  //read in chars from file and add them to a string (still encrypted)
}
```

I have tried several methods and I really thought this one would work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Encrypted.length(); i++) //for the length of the encrypted string
        {
            x = 0;                              //resets the string it is entering into; Array position 0
            for (key = 0; key < 255; key++)     //key used must be a lowercase letter
            {

                c = (uint8_t)Encrypted[x];                      //convert char 'x' of encrypted string to a byte
                uintOutput = (c ^ key);                         //XOR with current key guess
                charOutput = (char)uintOutput;                  //convert byte back to char again
                everything[x] = everything[x] + charOutput;     //add xor'd char to currently selected string
                x++;                                            //move to next array position; to next string
            }

        }
```

Where everything is an array of strings - everything[255], key is a byte representing the encryption/decryption key.

```
            for (int y = 0; y < (255* Encrypted.length()); y++)     //print out for number of possibilities
        {
            cout << everything[y] << endl << endl;
        }

return 0;
```

}
To run the program I am using a .bat file with file redirection in my case the bat file contains this: `program.exe < EncryptedText.bin >> ciphertext.bin`
Where EncryptedText.bin is a file that has been encrypted with an unknown key and ciphertext.bin is where the decrypted text is outputted.

The program builds fine, the file redirection is fine as I have used it with another program that guessed the key which was only a single character - not an unrestricted length.

The main issue I am having is an error message that pops up when I run the .bat file

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program:C:WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.ddl
>
> file i:\microsoft visual studio\vc\include\xstring
>
> Line:1681
>
> Expression: string subscript out of range
>
> ...(retry etc here)

I'd really appreciate any insight into this, I just cannot see where I have gone wrong and I have been messing around with this question for hours

Comment: This is known as a Vigenère cipher. There are lots of references on how to cryptanalyse it.

Comment: @AlanStokes It took me longer than I care to admit to realise that the answer to this one was 'sometimes'. Not quite the 3 years it took me to respond to your comment, but a while none-the-less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where you went wrong (only the relevant lines of code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Encrypted.length(); i++)
{
       x = 0;
       for (key = 0; key < 255; key++)
       {
                c = (uint8_t)Encrypted[x];

                // Some code here that's not relevant

                x++;
       }
}
```

As should be immediately obviously from this, your code will attempt to access `Encrypted[0]` through `Encrypted[254]`, so unless your `Encrypted` string is 254 characters long, this will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like here:

```
for (int y = 0; y < (255* Encrypted.length()); y++)
```

index goes out of `everything[255]`.